# Traverse Ireport Input control paramter of type collection(mutiselect parameter)

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a Oracle  query where I want to check content of a Ireport input control parameter of data type "collection" like below the SQL

```
select devlocview.floorname FROM AlarmDeviceView alrmDevView INNER JOIN devicelocationview devLocView ON devlocview.oid=alrmdevview.deviceoid
LEFT OUTER JOIN DEVICEGROUPVIEW devGrpView ON devlocview.oid=devgrpview.deviceoid
LEFT OUTER JOIN RackCapacityView rackCapView ON devlocview.RACKID=rackCapView.oid WHERE 
(
( $P{building.name} IS NOT NULL AND devlocview.buildingname = $P{building.name} )
       OR
       ( $P{building.name}='All Buildings' AND devlocview.buildingname IN (SELECT buildingname FROM  cdmr.devicelocationview ) )
    )
AND $X{IN, devlocview.floorname, floor.name}
```

Here
"floor.name" is the multiselect(collection type) inputcontrol parameter of Ireport which contains the value selected by the user in UI
"devlocview.floorname" SQL query output

Now I want to do something like

```
 IF USER SELECTS "ALL BUILDING" IN UI i.e. IF floor.name contains "ALL BUILDING"
     THEN DO SOMETHING 
   ELSE 
     THEN DO SOMETHING
```

The problem I am facing is I am not able to traverse and check  the contents of Ireport Input control parameter "floor.name" which is of type "collection"

Comment: Are you talking about *JasperReports Server* input parameters? *iReport* is just a GUI designer for constructing report's template

Comment: Yes Jasper server Input control

Comment: Do you mean check as in a checkbox, or check as in view the contents?